# Python call constructor of its own instance

Tags: python

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def create_another(self):
        return Foo()
        # is not working as intended, because it will make y below becomes Foo

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

x = Bar()
y = x.create_another()
```

y should be of class Bar not Foo.

Is there something like: `self.constructor()` to use instead?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For new-style classes, use `type(self)` to get the 'current' class:

```
def create_another(self):
    return type(self)()
```

You could also use `self.__class__` as that is the value `type()` will use, but using the API method is always recommended.

For old-style classes (python 2, not inheriting from `object`), `type()` is not so helpful, so you are forced to use `self.__class__`:

```
def create_another(self):
    return self.__class__()
```

Comment: @Billiska: Unless you have good reason to do so, I'd use new-style classes, though. Have `Foo` inherit from `object`.